# CheckBox Code Doesn't working there is no compile time error

Tags: gwt

public SubMenuItemCommand(MenuObject menuItem,JsArray listOfMenu,ToothWidget toothWidget){ this.menuItem=menuItem; this.listOfMenu=listOfMenu; this.toothWidget=toothWidget; }

cb1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

```
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    System.out.println(menuItem.getImage());
                    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) event.getSource()).getValue();
                    if (checked) {
                        System.out.println("hello3");
                        int left = toothWidget.getToothImage().getAbsoluteLeft();
                        int top =  toothWidget.getVPanel().getAbsoluteTop();//toothWidget.getToothImage().getAbsoluteTop();
                        Image im = new Image();
                        im.setUrl("images/"+menuItem.getImg());
                        int offx = left;
                        int offy = top;     
                        final PopupPanel popup1 = new PopupPanel(true);
                        popup1.setStylePrimaryName("transparent");
                        popup1.setPopupPosition(Math.max(offx, 0),Math.max(offy, 0));
                        //popup.add(im);
                        ToothWidget wgt = new ToothWidget(toothWidget.getToothNumber(),menuItem.getImg(), toothWidget.getTeeth());
                        toothWidget.getTeeth().getMap().get(toothWidget.getToothNumber()).put(menuItem.getName(), wgt);
                        wgt.setMenu(toothWidget.getMenu());
                        wgt.setPanel(popup1);
                        popup1.add(wgt);
                        popup1.show();
                    }

                    else{
                        ToothWidget wgt = toothWidget.getTeeth().getMap().get(toothWidget.getToothNumber()).remove(menuItem.getName());
                        wgt.getPanel().hide();
                    }
                }
             });
```

Comment: WITE -> What is the ERROR?

Comment: there is no error bt menuItem.getImage() doesn't work...and System.out.println(menuItem.getImage()) doest print anything....popup is occuring bt there is no image in it

Comment: @Override annotation for public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {...}
isn't there, don't need that?!!

Comment: Can you clean up you question. Its hard to read and add some information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: there is a checkbox and if i am checking the checkbox popup containing image must be occur...toothwidget is another class...i have added clickhandler on checkbox....

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is a path issue. i.e image location is not what you are setting up.

If you have **images** folder in your gwt module's **public** folder you need to use                             `im.setUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg());`

If you have images in your **war/images** you need to use
`im.setUrl(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg());`

Also you can always use FireFox/FireBug's Network/Image console to check which URL is being accessed.

Comment: i have attached the snap shot.....plz refer it..i have used ur suggetion bt doesn't work