# CheckBox clickhandler code doesn't work...there is no compile time error...look at the snap shot

Tags: gwt

CheckBox clickhandler code doesn't work...there is no compile time error...look at the snap [shotlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffiMo.png) at the snap shot in which there is no image in popup...i have highlighted it

```
            cb1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    System.out.println("hello2");
                    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) event.getSource()).getValue();
                    if (checked) {
                        System.out.println("hello3");
                        int left = toothWidget.getToothImage().getAbsoluteLeft();
                        int top =  toothWidget.getVPanel().getAbsoluteTop();//toothWidget.getToothImage().getAbsoluteTop();
                        Image im = new Image();
                        im.setUrl(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg());
                        System.out.println(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg());
                        int offx = left;
                        int offy = top;     
                        final PopupPanel popup1 = new PopupPanel(true);
                        popup1.setStylePrimaryName("transparent");
                        popup1.setPopupPosition(Math.max(offx, 0),Math.max(offy, 0));
                        //popup.add(im);
                        ToothWidget wgt = new ToothWidget(toothWidget.getToothNumber(),menuItem.getImg(), toothWidget.getTeeth());
                        toothWidget.getTeeth().getMap().get(toothWidget.getToothNumber()).put(menuItem.getName(), wgt);
                        wgt.setMenu(toothWidget.getMenu());
                        wgt.setPanel(popup1);
                        popup1.add(wgt);
                        popup1.show();
                    }

                    else{
                        ToothWidget wgt = toothWidget.getTeeth().getMap().get(toothWidget.getToothNumber()).remove(menuItem.getName());
                        wgt.getPanel().hide();
                    }
                }
             });
```

Comment: Are you writing code in Eclipse? Place a brakepoint inside and see if it is reached. If not check why? If it does then maybe an exception is thrown? Try using a try catch clause to see what happens? The System.Out.println might write something in debug console but is not recomended in a web application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CheckBox Code Doesn't working there is no compile time error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193435/checkbox-code-doesnt-working-there-is-no-compile-time-error)

Comment: Please close one of the questions - This one or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193435/checkbox-code-doesnt-working-there-is-no-compile-time-error .

Answer (score 0):

try this. It is better to use the ValueChangeHandler that works for sure and is used for changing values.

```
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
cb1.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
            Boolean isChecked = event.getValue();
            if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("hello3");
                    int left = toothWidget.getToothImage().getAbsoluteLeft();
                    int top =  toothWidget.getVPanel().getAbsoluteTop();//toothWidget.getToothImage().getAbsoluteTop();
                    Image im = new Image();
                    im.setUrl(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg());
                    System.out.println(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg());
                    int offx = left;
                    int offy = top;     
                    final PopupPanel popup1 = new PopupPanel(true);
                    popup1.setStylePrimaryName("transparent");
                    popup1.setPopupPosition(Math.max(offx, 0),Math.max(offy, 0));
                    //popup.add(im);
                    ToothWidget wgt = new ToothWidget(toothWidget.getToothNumber(),menuItem.getImg(), toothWidget.getTeeth());
                    toothWidget.getTeeth().getMap().get(toothWidget.getToothNumber()).put(menuItem.getName(), wgt);
                    wgt.setMenu(toothWidget.getMenu());
                    wgt.setPanel(popup1);
                    popup1.add(wgt);
                    popup1.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    ToothWidget wgt = toothWidget.getTeeth().getMap().get(toothWidget.getToothNumber()).remove(menuItem.getName());
                    wgt.getPanel().hide();
                }

        }
    });
}
```

Plus the images/ folder must be inside the war forlder (though i think you already know that having developed this site)

Also check what `menuItem.getImg()` returns. It might return only the filename but not the extension or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

WEB Dev 101 - Always use FireFox/FireBug's Network/Image console to check for URL mismatch . You will be seeing 404 errors for the Image path.

Where is YOUR Image located?

### 1) public folder parallel to your gwt.xml

If you have images folder in your gwt module's public folder you need to use `im.setUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg());`

or

### 2) webapps folder

If you have images in deployed into your war/images you need to use
**`im.setUrl(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg());`**

If the above does not solve the issue then you may not have the image at all under "images"

Comment: We know!!!!! SUCH A ICON APPEARS WHEN IMAGE PATH IS WRONG AND BROWSER CANNOT LOCATE THE IMAGE. USE FIREBUG TO CHECK YOUR BROWSER CONSOLE for 404 error.

Comment: Try Window.Alert(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/images/"+menuItem.getImg()); right below the setUrl statement. Get what is written in the messagebox that will appear and paste it in a browser.You will know if the code is executed, and what the url really is that you are trying to load